# Unable to import TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to import TailwindCSS but it does not seem to work as no CSS is applied.

I have it in my `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.2.7",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"
}
```

I have installed it via `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest`.

Index:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import MenuAppBar from './header';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Tail from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <MenuAppBar />
        <Tail />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App looks like this:

```js
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
    
export default function Tail(){
    return (
        <div class="chat-notification">
            <div class="chat-notification-logo-wrapper">
                <img class="chat-notification-logo" src="/img/logo.svg" alt="ChitChat Logo"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-notification-content">
                <h4 class="chat-notification-title">ChitChat</h4>
                <p class="chat-notification-message">You have a new message!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: When you say "no CSS is applied", are you referring to CSS from TailwindCSS specifically, or just in general? You don't seem to be applying any utility classes from TailwindCSS in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes some playing around with the imports and reviewing in detail everything you write, this happens to me so often and its usually just a really small type error that creates this.  check out your first import in your App file.  i noticed at the top it says
"import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css""  try adding a "./" before tailwind.   so it ends uo looking like this

import "./tailwindcss/tailwind"   If you are using vscode it helps when you begin typing the ./ when importing files becasue the pop-up displays the files you have in that immediate path.

I also recommend installing the automatic import extension, it helps alot!  I hope this work, cheers.

Comment: In this case `tailwindcss` is an external package from `node_modules`. `import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"` is the correct way to import the CSS file.